# How to use anaconda packages in python environment on a linux server?

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, anaconda

I have installed `anaconda` , and use `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu` to install `tensorflow` .

I activate `tensorflow` by using `source activate tensorflow` sucessfully, but I find that I can't use other `anaconda packages` , such as `pandas` .

How to use `tensorflow` and `anaconda packages` sucessfully?

Here is my operations and the versions of `anaconda` and `tensorflow`.

**anaconda version:**

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
anaconda                  5.3.0                    py37_0
```

**tensorflow version:**

```
(base) anonym2@amax:/data/anonym2/code$ source activate tensorflow 
(tensorflow) anonym2@amax:/data/anonym2/code$  python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
1.5.0
```

**import pandas in tensorflow environment:**

```
(tensorflow) anonym2@amax:/data/anonym2/code$ import pandas 
import: unable to open X server `localhost:10.0' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/364.
(tensorflow) anonym2@amax:/data/anonym2/code$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pandas as pd 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Comment: I solve my problem by installing packages I need in `tensorflow` environment , though it seems troublesome.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [conda usage](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) first.

`conda install -n your_env_name pandas` may solve import pandas error, and replace `your_env_name` into your own environment name.

You have to install packages as many as you need. To avoid this, you could create an environment with a specific version of anaconda python before installing tensorflow by `conda create -n your_env_name python=3.7 anaconda`. The python version can be changed as you want.